# Massive newbie error while using the PHP header() function

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to redirect to a .php page if the $validForm variable is TRUE.

Here's my code:

```
<?php session_start();
require("validationLibrary.php");
$validForm = true;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form - 1 of 2</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Registration - Part 1 of 2</h1>
        <p>Please fill in all the required information before submitting the information.</p>        
        <form action="registerFormOne.php" method="post">
            <dt>First Name:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="firstName" /></dd><br />
                <dd>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['firstName'])){
                            if(!validateRequired($_POST['firstName'])){
                                $validForm = false;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </dd><br />

            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="lastName" /></dd><br />
                <dd>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['lastName'])){
                            if(!validateRequired($_POST['lastName'])){
                                $validForm = false;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </dd><br />

            <dt>EMail:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="email" /></dd><br />
                <dd>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
                            if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])){
                                $validForm = false;        
                            }
                        }                        
                    ?>
                </dd><br />

            <dt>Age:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="age" /></dd><br />
                <dd>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['age'])){
                            if(!validateNumber($_POST['age'])){
                                $validForm = false;        
                            }
                        }                        
                    ?>
                </dd><br />

            <dt>Date of Birth:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" /></dd><br />
                <dd>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['dateOfBirth'])){
                            if(!validateRequired($_POST['dateOfBirth'])){
                                $validForm = false;        
                            }
                        }                        
                    ?>
                </dd><br />

            <dt>Gender:</dt>
                <dd>Masculino <input type="radio" value="M" name="gender" checked/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                Femenino <input type="radio" value="F" name="gender" />
                </dd>            

            <dt><input type="submit" /></dt>

            <?php
                if($validForm = true){                    
                    header("Location: registerFormTwo.php");                    
                    exit;
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\registerFormOne.php:18) in C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\registerFormOne.php  on line 84

Comment: The first thing the documentation mentions is the solution to your problem.  Consider google for your next "massive newbie error", it'd be a lot faster.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP headers must be sent before **any** content is.

Which means your calls to the [`header()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) have to be done before you do any output *(quoting)* :

> Remember that `header()` must be called
>   before any actual output is sent,
>   either by normal HTML tags, blank
>   lines in a file, or from PHP.

A pretty standard way to achive that is to :

- **put all validation code at the beginning of your script**, before any HTML output
- that validation code will :

  - either redirect, using `header` if everything is OK
  - or set variables, to keep track of errors
- and, only after that, you'll use the variables set before, to re-display your form, if that is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Headers must be sent before any information is printed to the page. You must not call `header()` before echoing the HTML.

Comment: For that matter, all the validation should be done before any HTML is output.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the form validation and HTML generation parts. Validate the form first, optionally redirect, otherwise generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `header()` after you put contents on the page -- you have to do so before (Any character outputted to the client will cause it to not work. The page has to be completely blank).

In other words...

`<html>`

Is already too much.

What you should do is check if the form input is valid before echoing any HTML, and if it is, use `header()` to redirect, otherwise echo the HTML.